# keep html contents at same position and size ratio in full screen mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have being researching regarding this question for a long time but I was not lucky. Here is the situation. Assume you have a blue rectangle in the center of the page. When you go full screen, we can use percentage for height and width to preserve the ratio of rectangle. However, the position of rectangle changes and it moves up and you end up with extra space at the bottom of the page.

So what should I do to keep rectangle in the center of the page (equal vertical and horizontal distance) when full screen mode is enabled? In other words, if your screen is 1280x800, center of rectangle be at (640,400)

If you check home page of Chrome browser, when you go full screen, the position of apps stay the same and you don't end up with extra space at the bottom. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `width` of the rectangle and use `margin: 0 auto;` to center it in page horizontally.

If you want to center a `div` horizontally and vertically, use something like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="rectangle"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#rectangle {
   width: 30%; //can set any value here
   height: 20%; //can set any value here
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   margin-left: -15%; //negative half of width
   margin-top: -10%; //negative half of height
   background-color: red;
}​
```

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PbeSK/).

***OR***

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="rectangle"></div>
  </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: visible; 
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper[id] {
    display: table; 
    position: static;
}
#container[id] {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    width: 100%;
}
#rectangle {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 100px; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    background-color: blue;
}
```

​
See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PbeSK/2/).

Comment: it will center the page horizontally but in full screen, rectangle distance from top and bottom is not equal

Comment: yes it does :) thanks, one very small issue, when we use 50% for top, rectangle stays in its place. In firefox, rectangle is closer to top and in chrome & safari, rectangle is closer to bottom. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm. Added another way to center. Try it out, and see if this solves the difference in spacing b/w Chrome & FF. Oh and do accept the answer if you found it useful. Thanks :)

Comment: Now all browsers look similar. But this time scroll bar appears. Im very thankful so far. If you could tell me how to keep the page limited so there would not be any need to scroll, fiddle doesnt show the scroll bar

Comment: Change `overflow:visible` to `overflow:hidden` and try.

Comment: Done :) Awesome, exactly what I needed, thanks a million @abhshkdz I will mark ur answer. Bonus question if you had time. If we replace the blue rectangle with a slide show box, we can use the same technique as above? wouldnt that affect the contents inside the slideshow?

Comment: Nope not at all, anything you place within the rectangle div should stay centered just fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried also using percentages for the margins, for example if you centre square was 60% tall and wide you could add the 20% as a margin so that would also scale up. Without trying I don't know if it would give you the desired effect but it should fix the issue of the square moving up.

Comment: I have tried so many combinations like you suggested, this would be true if you are in normal mode, I dont if it is browser doing this or not

Comment: does it do the same in all browsers or is it different in each one.

Comment: I would say the other answers you have got are probably the best thing to try

Answer (score 1):

oops,

I forget that I am working on an iMac.
the if addition in the script solved my problem.

```
function vertical_center()
{
    var ww = $(window).width();
    if (ww < 1600)
    {
    $("#character").css({'width': ww + 'px','height': (ww/4) + 'px', 'margin-top': -(ww/8) + 'px'});
    }
    else
    $("#character").css({'width': ww + 'px'})
}
```

Yet, I would be glad if someone looks over my code telling me where some silly things remain.
Hope this post added something nevertheless, thank you guys